# Converting to png<image> or base64 from canvas does'nt work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, image, canvas

Actually i am having grid div element with number of html tags like `<div>` , `<p>, <img>` and converting it to canvas then **base64** for saving on server by php.

can anyone help me to get rid this issue. 
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/manish1706/ujx6rh5j/3/) is my code https://jsfiddle.net/manish1706/ujx6rh5j/3/

I am unable to having images that is in `<img />` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations):

> All the images that the script uses need to reside under the [same origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

So since your image is cross-origin, Html2Canvas can't access it.

---

[Here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/175) writes about [proxy](https://github.com/adjdred/html2canvas-proxy-php) usage for this.

Answer (score 0):

first Thanks to @Justinas for point out cross origin issue , 
I used

```
html2canvas($(".frameGrid"),
        {
            useCORS: true,
            "proxy":"http://xxxxxx.com/xxxx/timthumb.php", // optional (and if you are not writing this so have to all origin by server side)
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            $('#img-out').append('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
        }
    });
```

and for future use i used

```
header('Access-Control-Max-Age:' . 5 * 60 * 1000);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Request-Method: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

in my cross server side php file.